# Why does "dO----------" in a vimrc mapped macro throw the error "E488: Trailing characters"?

Tags: vim

In my vimrc, I have a fold marker, a function, and a mapped macro:

```
set foldmarker=----------,++++++++++++

"Function to switch INTO visual line mode, not just toggle
function SwitchToVisLine()
    if visualmode()!="V"
        execute "normal! V"
    endif
endfunction

"Macro to wrap and fold visually highlighted lines
xnoremap <F3> :call SwitchToVisLine()
              \dO
              \----------<CR>
              \++++++++++<ESC>
              \k0pzako
```

The point is to be able to go from any of the three visual modes and tap `<F3>` to have the active lines wrapped in the fold markers, folded, and the cursor returned on a new line above the whole mess.

PROBLEM: When using the macro as written, I get the error `E488: Trailing characters: dO----------`

What's confusing is that when I walk through each keystroke manually, even calling the function to switch from visual or visual-block mode into visual-line mode, I DON'T get this error. It only happens when I run it as a mapped macro.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its current form, your attempt at making a multiline macro looks like this to Vim with the line continuation characters removed:

```
:call SwitchToVisLine()dO----------<CR>++++++++++<ESC>k0pzako
                      /\
                     <CR>
```

which is incorrect due to the missing `<CR>` after `:call SwitchToVisLine()`.

It should look like this:

```
xnoremap <F3> :call SwitchToVisLine()<CR>
              \dO
              \----------<CR>
              \++++++++++<ESC>
              \k0pzako
```

That said, there are quite a few improvement opportunities, here.

- The macro could be replaced with two `:help :silent` `:help :put` commands:

  ```
  xnoremap <F3> :sil'<put!='----------'\|sil'>put='++++++++++'<CR>
  ```

  which:

  - makes your custom function unnecessary because there is no need to force visual-line mode anymore,
  - doesn't pollute any register,
  - is not destructive.
- You could use the value of `foldmarker` instead of repeating yourself:

  ```
  xnoremap <F3> :sil'<put!=&fmr->split(',')[0]\|sil'>put=&fmr->split(',')[1]<CR>
  ```

Ten lines to one, nice.

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for! The problem now seems to be that when in visual mode and pressing `:` the prompt goes straight to `:'<,'>` which doesn't seem to play nice with the `'<` and `'>` at the start of the two `put` commands. When running the macro as you wrote, I get the error `E492: Not an editor command: ` Any advice there?

Comment: Follow up, this is my final macro: 
```
set foldmarker=----------,++++++++++
xnoremap <F3> <ESC>:'<put!='----------'\|'>put='++++++++++'<CR>kza0
````
The trick was exiting visual mode, which eliminates the auto-inserted range `'<,'>` when entering a command, then using @romainl's answer above. I went with the explicit fold markers rather than the variable reference since it's fewer characters overall, and easier to understand. Also had to drop the `:sil` calls because they were causing errors when combined with `<CR>` near the end. Thanks!

Comment: You can also prepend the command with `<C-u>` to empty the command-line: `:<C-u>sil'<…` or use `:help <Cmd>`.